# Enforcing id relationships on models

Tags: java, oop

I have two model objects that have the following relation ship.

```
A {
 int id;
 List<B> bList;
}
B {
 int id;
 int idA; // references a particular object A with associated id
}
```

Class A has a list of objects of type B. The problem is that I don't know if it is good practice to enforce this relationship. That is make sure that id of B has an id of A. Right now, i'm considering having an A object return a builder object that will build B objects that have idA set to the proper id for the current instance.. Is this a good practice or not?

**Edit:**
I forgot some details. I thought it over some more and I realize that isn't the only reason I may be using a builder. Object B also has a list of objects that varies based on the particular instance of A. So every A object essentially has a different B object. My knowledge of design patterns, which isn't that much at all, tells me to use a builder pattern, which I stated above. What do you people think?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing this on DB level using PK FK constraints.
But if you want them on your code the closest Structural Pattern in my opinion is the Composite pattern.
I suggest making the list of available Objects of A shared, and another subList for each A of B references whenever it is referenced by B, this makes it easy to destroy(remove) references from B whenever A is no longer exist.
Additionaly it makes sure you are not adding A that is not exist, and keep consistent and coherent structure.

```
 Public static List<Structure> mainList; // This must be updated whenever A created or instantiated by B

 Class Structure{
 Public A obj= new A();
 Public List<B> referencesOfA=new ArrayList<B>();
 }

  A {
  int id;
  List<B> bList;
  }
  B {
  int id;
  int idA; // references a particular object A with  associated id
   }
```

See:
https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/composite

Comment: Well, these objects are suppose to be business objects. So I believe that possibility is already handled by the database. That structure you presented. Isn't it similar to a weak table, table that only models the relationships?

Comment: If you want to force this relationship in your business logic NOT you DB, this is the way to maintain integrity, may not be the best.

Comment: So you think I should just let the DB enforce it. I'd rather have the DB do it if possible. Basically, I am overthinking this design, right?